# How to create a "listening(waiting?)" method

Tags: php, class, methods

Lets say I have:

```
class X
{
    function a()
    {
        echo "Hello, ";
    }
    function b()
    {
        echo "John!";
    }
}
```

and then

```
Y = new X();
Y->a();
```

but once the method a is called, I also want the method b called immediately after it (so it kind of listens(waits?) till the moment when a is called and finished), so the output is

```
Hello, John
```

Is it possible to do that, and how that should look?
And no, calling $this->b(); at the end of method a is NOT a solution to what I want to do :) Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How about calling $Y->b() after $Y->a()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching for [observer pattern](http://labelmedia.co.uk/blog/posts/php-design-patterns-observer-pattern.html). Read some example from the internet, you should be able to do what you are attempting.

However, A very simple example of using observer pattern:

```
class X
{
    private $observer;
    public function __construct() {
        $this -> observer = new XObserver();
    }

    function a() {
        echo "Hello,";      
        $this -> observer -> aExecuted($this);
    }

    function b() {
        echo "John!";
    }
}

class XObserver {

    public function aExecuted($obj) {
        return $obj -> b(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I often have trouble naming things whilst googling. Appreciated :)

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius, You can check a simple example i created.

Comment: The only minor thing that I do not like is that $this -> observer -> aExecuted($this); still needs to be added to the method. Any ways to prevent that but still make it work like it does now?

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius, You can override the __call() to trap the call and do whatever you like with the script.

Comment: Overriding __call() seems like a perfect solution! :O

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius, May be, but use the magic functions with a lot of care.

Answer (score -1):

Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to do? Because observer pattern suggested it involves attaching a list of external objects and implementing some kind of event-based system. And i am not sure that the observer approach fits your needs from what you describe.

There is basicly no possibility to call another method once a method has finished running, and i don't see the need for it. A semi correct approach could be to use __call and make the a() method protected/private, and in the __call intercept the call, run method a() and immediately run method b().

Unfortunatelly without much details i cannot provide or think of a better way to solve this problem. There are no php magic methods for this purpose.

Comment: After some methods like create/read/update/delete, I want the info of the user's access to these functions to be written into database. For some children of the main class, these methods can be different and every time I have not to forget to put that call to database writer method line after each method. Quite a hassle in my opinion.